# loaded php code from mysql table doesn't interpret on the output page

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to make use of someone else's cms design as he stores his page content inside mysql table.
i updated table manually and inserted following code:

```
<?php echo (int)$height ?>
```

Output page like said doesn't interpret code but rather displays it as a plain text.

This is how this guy fetch his content data:

```
echo html_entity_decode(stripcslashes(FetchFromTable("tbl_page","page_content","page_id", $_GET['page_id'])));
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: it doesn't produce PHP related output but instead it just displays `<?php echo (int)$height ?>` on the page. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put PHP code into the content of that CMS system. It doesn't support it.

Comment: Thanks man. Although I believe you, cause this guy's code is messy, I would appreciate quick why, as I am cooler than him. ;)

Comment: @daniel.tosaba because the code doesn't evaluate anything returned from the database.

Comment: Any tip to quick fix this?? Can I insert evaluation somewhere in that line of code I posted above??? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wait, maybe I am just reading this wrong, because it is a bit absurd, but are we talking about php code inside the database?

If that is actually the case, you could change

```
echo html_entity_decode(stripcslashes(FetchFromTable("tbl_page","page_content","page_id", $_GET['page_id'])));
```

to

```
echo eval("?>".html_entity_decode(stripcslashes(FetchFromTable("tbl_page","page_content","page_id", $_GET['page_id']))));
```

Though the implications of this are **huge**, **especially** if these parts of the database are user editable. You might be opening the application to all kinds of fun hacks.

The proper way would be finding out how he manages dynamic content inside that HTML and do it the same way.

Comment: It works for PHP but now are HTML tags being displayed as plain text. You know how to hack this one??? Thanks man

Comment: My bad, I updated the answer. Though it will mess up all backslashes and html encoded characters you enter into the PHP code. Eval does not return its result, it outputs it directly. Also, just to emphasize: YOU SHOULD NOT DO THIS ON A LIVE WEB SITE!